# RESTfull controllers with more than CRUD methods

Tags: php, rest, laravel

This is something I don't understand quite well I making making an App for my self using Laravel and would like to upkeep to standards.

So I have the following:

```
class UserController extends BaseController {

    GET index(), show(), new(), edit()        
    POST create()
    PUT update()
    DELETE destroy()
}

class UserModel { hasMany->Assets }

class Asset { pulic function fetchAssetsFromApi(); }
```

Now I don't have an Asset controller because there is nothing about Asset that needs to be displayed on it's own. I simply have the model for the ORM purposes to represent `assets` table.

Now the Assets model has a method that pulls Assets associated with a particular User and adds them to the database.

Now my view that is rendered by `UserController->show` has a button called Update Assets that should call `fechAssetsFromApi()` to update characters assets. However since there is no way to invoke alone with a button I would have to POST to a controller.

Meaning now I would need to have another method in my `UsersController` since it's the only one that will be using Assets model.

Now my question is does this break *rules and guidelines* for RESTfull controllers ? I will have this similar dilema appear multiple time in application ho should i approach it.

Should a proper RESTFull controller contain only CRUD or ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, having more functions in a controller is fine, but you should only have your public functions be your CRUD functions.  In this case, I would just make a link that, when clicked, will just go back to the that same route.  This means that the same `show()` function will be called, except anything that has been updated will now be pulled to the page.  Essentially force a refresh of the browser page.